# "No KeyInfo Generator provided" for spring-security-saml2-service-provider

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-saml2

I have an application that connects to a SAML idP that only supports the POST Binding. After configuring my application which uses spring-security-saml2-service-provider to manually create a POST Authentication request, I looked at the XML that got generated and saw that it included the Signature information (which is expected) but not the Key Info. Then in the logs, I noticed it said:

`No KeyInfoGenerator was supplied in parameters or resolveable for credential type org.opensaml.security.x509.X509Credential, No KeyInfo will be generated for Signature`

This is what my code looks like to manually generate the POST Authentication request:

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic()
                .disable()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public RelyingPartyRegistration nnanetRelyingPartyRegistration() {
        SAMLMetadataSignatureSigningParametersResolver resolver = new SAMLMetadataSignatureSigningParametersResolver();

        return RelyingPartyRegistrations
                .fromMetadataLocation("https://example.com/metadata.xml")
                .entityId("example")
                .registrationId("nnanet")
                .assertingPartyDetails(party -> {
                    party.wantAuthnRequestsSigned(true)
                        .singleSignOnServiceLocation("https://example.com/login")
                        .entityId("https://example.com/login");
                        .verificationX509Credentials(saml2X509Credentials -> {
                            saml2X509Credentials.add(getVerificationCertificate());
                        });
                })
                .signingX509Credentials(saml2X509Credentials -> {
                    saml2X509Credentials.add(getSigningCredential());
                })
                .decryptionX509Credentials(saml2X509Credentials -> {
                    saml2X509Credentials.add(getSigningCredential());
                })
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RelyingPartyRegistrationRepository relyingPartyRegistrationRepository() {
        return new InMemoryRelyingPartyRegistrationRepository(relyingPartyRegistration());
    }

    @Bean
    public Saml2PostAuthenticationRequest saml2PostAuthenticationRequest() {
        Saml2AuthenticationRequestContext.Builder contextBuilder = Saml2AuthenticationRequestContext.builder();
        contextBuilder.assertionConsumerServiceUrl("http://localhost:8080/saml/SSO");
        contextBuilder.relyingPartyRegistration(relyingPartyRegistration());
        contextBuilder.issuer("issuer");

        OpenSamlAuthenticationRequestFactory factory = new OpenSamlAuthenticationRequestFactory();

        return factory.createPostAuthenticationRequest(contextBuilder.build());
    }
```

I just call the `saml2PostAuthenticationRequest()` method from my Controller and generate a form to submit automatically due to some reasons that are outside the scope of this question. After looking further into the `OpenSamlAuthenticationRequestFactory`, it looks like this is creating the `SignatureSigningParameters` specifically without including the `KeyInfoGenerator` as it's only being created in the private methods. Does anyone have an idea on how to get around this, or perhaps point out if I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will be addressed in a future version of Spring Security SAML 2

Please review the PR - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/9746